# How to import Athena in a React App using aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I already imported the `aws-sdk` NPM package in my React app and then when I import Athena like this,

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var athena = new AWS.Athena();
```

As the documentation specified, but it will show an error like this:

```
TypeError: AWS.Athena is not a constructor
```

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `node_modules` directory and running `npm i` again? Also, if you have only those two lines in your file, does the problem still occur?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek i already deleted the node modules but still, it doesnt work

Comment: If you leave only those two lines in your file, does the problem still occur?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, yes

Comment: It seems to work in a clean environment: https://repl.it/repls/EducatedTerribleDecagon. Is there anything more that is happening in your project?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek There may be a difference between a purely clean NodeJS environment and a ReactJS environment. I'm running into the exact same issue in a blank ReactJS application